# In cross validation, should the test dataset not be fixed

Tags: neural-network, cross-validation, validation

Would this work?

We want to train a neural net.

We have 50 datapoints and want a split of 30 for train, 10 for validation, 10 for test.

We want to do 5-fold cross validation.

We use the following pseudo code to evaluate a configuration of hyperparameters.

```
For each of the 5 folds:
    Randomly split the 50 datapoints between train, val, test.
    While validation loss decreases:
        Train model on training dataset (training to minimise loss).
        Calculate model loss on validation dataset.

    Calculate model loss on test dataset and store in array test_losses_array.

Calculate the average of test_losses_array. This is the score for this configuration.
```

So each of the folds would have a different test dataset, which is where I believe this different from usual where the test dataset is fixed. Why is it better to fix the test dataset and not do what I have done? It seems like changing the test dataset each time reduces the risk of the test dataset simply being a test set that is easy to perform well on.

I guess we could use the same test dataset to evaluate all configurations, why is this better than what I propose (changing the test dataset every fold for every configuration)?

Also if there are any other problems with my training loop, please shout them out.

Answer (score 1):

What you are trying to do is called Nested cross-validation. Nested cross-validation is an approach to model hyperparameter optimization and model selection that attempts to overcome the problem of overfitting the training dataset. Take a look at [this post](https://machinelearningmastery.com/nested-cross-validation-for-machine-learning-with-python/) to learn more about it.